# Composer HTTP 400 Bad request when downloading Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

I am getting an issue of 400 bad request connecting over http, and it seems the package only wants to be installed via http. I tried an override in composer.json as tried by others as workaround to force https - but that doesn't seem to work. I'm not behind a firewall. Mac OS 10.10.3

**Issue :**

```
composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: FAIL
the property name is required
the property description is required
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]    

The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$c2596c5d04e7701561420666ba120ede9429a69c75b732a5a01b18ebb3d64e53.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
```

Composer.json

```
{
"repositories": [
     { "packagist": false }
,

    {
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
]
}
```

Composer version 1.0-dev (92faf1c7a83a73794fb914a990be435e1df373ca)
 2015-07-14 12:37:15

Comment: Can you post output for `cat composer.json` and your current composer version ?

Comment: `curl -IL http://packagist.org/p/provid...` works for both `http` and `https` from my local.  What do you get via curl?

Comment: Yes Curl works for http 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 02:09:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1072
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 02:09:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55a863ca-430"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

Comment: Did you do any change to your composer.json? Could you post last changes registered with get? Please provide the meaningful file contents by editing your question instead of posting hard to read comments.

Comment: basically composer.json was blank when I started, then I added the https option

Answer (score 5):

For me quitting Forticlient (antivirus/web security app) removed the 400 bad request error and allowed me to download laravel via composer.

Maybe you have antivirus software or similar that is interfering.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.11

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and I use composer diagnose -vvv

```
Checking git settings: Executing command (CWD): git config color.ui
OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: Downloading http://packagist.org/packages.json
FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
```

Because I install Forticlient, stop it and everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am installing Yii2 on my Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.06 and resolved as follows.

In my case I had to **close** an application (antivirus/web security app)

> **FortiClient** Aplication Close

Then try again to make the composer command

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```